# How to find the indices of an ndarray in another ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have arrays of `a = np.arange(21).reshape(7,3)` and `b = np.array([[3,4,5], [9,10,11]])`

```
a = [[ 0  1  2]
     [ 3  4  5]
     [ 6  7  8]
     [ 9 10 11]
     [12 13 14]
     [15 16 17]
     [18 19 20]]

b = [[3  4  5]
     [9 10 11]]
```

I want to find the row numbers of b within a. So, I am looking to get **1 and 3** as my **output**. I know that for finding the indices, I can use the `np.where()` or `np.argwhere()`. However, I don't know exactly if we can use them for this problem or I have to use other functions. I tried `c = np.argwhere(a == b)` but it gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [np.argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [3, 4, 5],
              [6, 7, 8],
              [9, 10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17],
              [18, 19, 20]])

b = np.array([[3, 4, 5],
              [9, 10, 11]])

res = np.argwhere(
    (a == b[:, None])  # compare all rows of a vs b
    .all(axis=2)  # find the ones where all the elements matches
)[:, 1]  # use argwhere to find indices, but only use the column indices

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1 3]
```

**UPDATE**
For finding the missing ones do the following, I splitted the steps to make it easier to understand:

```
matches = (a == b[:, None]).all(axis=2)
print(matches)

res = np.argwhere(~matches.any(axis=1))[:, 0]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[False  True False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False]]
[1]
```

The first part of the output, shows two rows that correspond to the rows in `b`, as it can be seen the first row of `b` has a match in with the second row of `a`. The second row of, has no matches.

The second part of the output shows the result of applying argwhere for selecting the indices where there is not row of `a` matching one in `b` (`~matches.any(axis=1)`).

Comment: that was perfect. It worked. Just I was curious to know if we can find what rows of b that is  not found in a? imagine I had b = np.array([[3,4,5], [21,22,23]]). Can I get the output of 1 which corresponds to the second row of b which is not in a?

Comment: @Peyman Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.